# How to get list of record within a range using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to integrate Google Map on my page, but before I integrate, I need to extract data from the database in a way that, I need to extract the lat and lon of a place then I want to extract those places also which are nearby the extracted place lat/lon.

I have a query which need mofiication

```
public static List<PlaceMap> GetPlace(this IEnumerable<Place> places, string hotelName, ref DataEntities ctx)
{             
   var place= ctx.places
       .Where(h=>h.HotelName==hotelName)
       .Select(s => new PlaceMap
       {
           PlaceName= s.PlaceName,
           Latitude = s.Latitude,
           Longitude = s.Longitude,
           NearByPlaces = ????

        }).SingleOrDefault();
    return place;
}
```

Comment: You are hopefully aware your code will now work, whatever you assign to `NearByPlaces`? Your methods signature indicates you want to return a `List<PlaceMap>`, but you are assigning a single item (null if none found, exception thrown if several hotels with a given name) to your return variable (`place`).

Comment: Also - why is this an extension method on `IEnumerable<Place>`? `places` variable is not used in the method in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NearByPlaces = (from p in ctx.places
                where p.Latitude > s.Latitude - latrange && 
                      p.Latitude < s.Latitude + latrange &&
                      p.Longitude > s.Longitude - longrange && 
                      p.Longitude < S.Longitude + longrange
                select /* whatever */).ToArray()
```

That being said, such a query can be rather inefficient if you have a lot of places (e.g. millions) and you don't have a spatial index on your database. Obviously, in order to have a spatial index, you need to use spatial types to store the location, not separate Latitude and Longitude columns. In SQL Server, you would use a SqlGeography column. That could be queried with the entity framework as a DbGeography.

This should answer your actual question, but it will of course not solve the other issues with your method, see the comments others have posted to your question.

Comment: This is what work for me for the current database design. I don't have places in millions. I only have 210 max.

Comment: @user3398887 If you have only 210 places, this is your answer. You do not need `SqlGeography` nor `DbGeography`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out DBGeography of Entity Framework:

```
public static List<PlaceMap> GetPlace(this IEnumerable<Place> places, string hotelName, ref DataEntities ctx)
{
    var place= ctx.places
        .Where(h=>h.HotelName==hotelName)
        .Select(s => new PlaceMap
        {
            PlaceName= s.PlaceName,
            Latitude = s.Latitude,
            Longitude = s.Longitude,
            NearByPlaces = ctx.places.Where
            (
                x=>
                DbGeography.FromText("POINT(" + s.Longitude + " " + s.Latitude + ")")  
                .Distance
                (
                    DbGeography.FromText("POINT(" + x.Longitude + " " + x.Latitude + ")")
                ) < YourRadiousInMeters
            )                  
        }).SingleOrDefault();
    return place;
}
```

Comment: Using the .Distance function would result in a circular area being covered. Since the OP wants to display these on a map, I assume a rectangular area is needed.

Comment: What Assembly reference will be needed for DbGeography? This is what I am looking for

Comment: System.Data.Entity       using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

Comment: Ok Got the namespace which were needed. I don't get it what I suppose to write in place of "YourRadiousInMeters"?

Comment: OK. Got it. Thanks for DbGeography example. I will need to change database in order to make it work.

Comment: @user3398887 You don't need to change the database for this to work, but you may need to change it to work fast. See also my answer.

Comment: If you want an area of 50Km radius then YourRadiousInMeters should be 50.000

Comment: Kris has a point on the difference of a circle(my solution) and of a rectangle(his solution)